# Is it possible to have each status for each parameter if I use conditional statements with &&?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have some problem with my program. I have this condition, which condition the value I get from research in my laboratory. So, I will input the  value to database.

```
Parameter | Standard | Value
------------------------------
H2O       | Max.7    | (ex.6)
NaCl      | Min.94   | (ex.93)
```

I must use the syntax IF with AND condition from my lecturer. But, beside that syntax I must passed the status for each parameter to database. So, the result will be like this :

```
Parameter | Standard | Value | Status
-------------------------------------
H20       | Max.7    | 6     | PASSED
NaCl      | Min.94   | 90    | DENIED
```

Can I get the each value with status like what I want if I use AND ? This is my syntax IF with AND :

```
if(($air<=7) && ($nacl>=94) && ($tidaklarut<=0.5) && ($yodium>=30) && ($kadmium<=0.5) && ($timbal<=10) && ($raksa<=0.1) && ($arsen<=0.1))
{
$status = "Passed";
}
```

Comment: What's the question ? What do you want to achieve ? Can you explain better ?

Comment: thankyou @aleroot for your edited, it looks better than before , would you like to gimme some help ? :)

Comment: and I totally don't understand why you're using php variables for comparing?

Comment: @UtariOktavianti If your question is whether the syntax is right - yes it is. That is the way to do it. If only one of the conditions in the conjunction fails (equals `FALSE`) `$status = "Passed";` won't be executed.

Comment: @UtariOktavianti if you explain better what you need, i will help ;-)

Comment: @aleroot I wanna have the status PASSED or DENIED for each Parameter based on the Value that I entered. I already know what should I do is check the Value One By One if I want to have specific Status. But, my lecturer gimme assignment to not use IF..ELSE but use IF && and also have the Status for each parameter. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @T-ShirtDude so if I cannot use php variables? what should I do?

Comment: I am guessing from your code that you're storing all the values of '`Value`' column from SQL database to php variable? If it's the other way round, then its fine. :)

Comment: @T-ShirtDude the first data that stored in database only parameter and standard. the values of 'Value' I input using textfield. so when I click submit button, there will be execution to see if the Value that I entered before will be listed as Passed or Denied...

Answer (score 1):

@utari-oktavianti I cannot comment yet, but you already have used what your lecturer asked you to use to get the final result of the test or whatever it is they do at the lab with 'IF &&' now you have to use single if statement per every variable you are testing (the if...else). There is no other way (I mean there are different approaches, but the 'IF &&' is not one of them).

an example would be:

```
$_status = array();
if($air<=7) {
    $_status['air'] = 'passed';
}
else {
    $_status['air'] = 'denied';
}
```

Alternatively if you really don't want to use 'else' set your default values first and only override them if they pass ie.

```
$_status         = array();
$_status['air']  = 'denied';
$_status['nacl'] = 'denied';
if($air<=7) {
    $_status['air']  = 'passed';
}
if($nacl>=94) {
    $_status['nacl'] = 'passed';
}
```

Hope this helps,
Mike

Comment: okay, I'll try your code. so, I will use foreach to store the status ?

Comment: @utari-oktavianti yes, while not optimal, for your thesis should be enough to just fire the sql update statement in a foreach loop to add the status to your existing rows. (Unless it's some sort of programming degree you are hoping to obtain).